# Is it possible to distinguish between window splits?

Tags: vim, split, window

Does vim offer a function or somehow return an indicator to distinguish between the type of split windows? I want to be able to track if a split is horizontal or vertical.
I want to use the information in a script to run certain actions depending on if the split is H or V.

Comment: can't you see it (by your eyes) if the split is H or V? what do you really want to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check if a window is in a horizontal split for example, you could get its height and compare it with the total screen height.

```
if winheight(0) + &cmdheight + 1 != &lines
  " current window is part of a horizontal split
endif
```

(the condition factors in the height of the command line and the status line as well).

For vertical split check, all you need is:

```
if winwidth(0) != &columns
   " current window is in a vertical split
endif
```

Comment: Thanks for you solution! I thought vim would offer some builtin functionality but your approach is pretty fine, too. ;) (Not tested yet, but whilel lookin at the code I think this should do it very well.)